# How do I prevent Twitter bootstrap Table cell streching

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap table. I insert images to the table cells. However, when I change the browser width, the image width changes accordingly. I want to keep the images always as the original width and height. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you're using bootstrap version 2.x.x. if yes, set `max-width:none` to avoid the image resizing in a table.

```
.table td img {
   max-width:none;
 }
```

See the difference between http://bootply.com/81876 where it uses `max-width:none` and http://bootply.com/81875 .

In bootstrap 3, you have to use `img-responsive` class to images to get responsive behaviour.